# How to turn on/off Hotjar dynamically without page reloading

Tags: cookies, hotjar

I have a web application using Hotjar to track user's information and behavior while they navigate through it, but I would like to give the user the possibility to turn on/off Hotjar tracking.

The idea is to have a check button that would turn on when selected and off when deselected. I was thinking also that this action could use some specific cookies, that would tell Hotjar the tracking is on or off dynamically.

Is it possible? If so, is it possible without page reloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this position from HotJar support, it is not yet possible to turn off using events.

[image: Hotjar Position]